# Cálculo de processamento do procesador

Tags: arquitetura-computadores

Galera, é possível calcular a velocidade de um processador para executar uma instrução e várias instruções?

Comment: Depende da velocidade de oscilação do `clock` e da arquitetura do processador, também das estrategias utilizadas para execução de uma ou mais tarefas (tipo pipeline, entre outras), e também de muitos outros fatores...

Comment: Olá alexsander, bem vindo ao [pt.so]. Percebi que teve várias perguntas fechadas recentemente, para aumentar suas chances de conseguir uma boa resposta sugiro que leia o guia [ask] e faça um [tour].

Answer (score 1):

Se você pegar o manual de um processador, encontra o número de ciclos de clock que uma instrução qualquer leva para executar. Você encontra manuais de processadores Intel em http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html.

Então, em tese, se uma instrução leva um ciclo para executar, e o processador tem 2GHz, ele executaria 2 bilhões de vezes essa instrução por segundo, ou cada instrução levaria 0.5ns para executar.

Só que isso é na teoria. Na prática, o acesso a memória fora do cache demora dezenas ou centenas de ciclos para buscar essa memória para dentro do cache. Alguns processadores conseguem executar instruções em paralelo, então o custo real em ciclos de um conjunto de instruções é bastante difícil de prever com exatidão.